# Time Limit Exceeded on Leetcode: How can I optimize my code more in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, sliding-window

I am trying to solve the Sliding Window Maximum question on leetcode. It's giving me Time Limit Exceeded so I guess my code isn't optimized well and needs more efficient solutions. But I tried to optimize my solution but still got Time Limit Exceeded on leetcode.

Ques1: Sliding Window Maximum

> You are given an array of integers nums, there is a sliding window of size k which is moving from the very left of the array to the very right. You can only see the k numbers in the window. Each time the sliding window moves right by one position.

> Return the max sliding window.

> Example:
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [1,3,-1,-3,5,3,6,7], k = 3
> Output: [3,3,5,5,6,7]
> Explanation: 
> Window position                Max
> ---------------               -----
> [1  3  -1] -3  5  3  6  7       3
>  1 [3  -1  -3] 5  3  6  7       3
>  1  3 [-1  -3  5] 3  6  7       5
>  1  3  -1 [-3  5  3] 6  7       5
>  1  3  -1  -3 [5  3  6] 7       6
>  1  3  -1  -3  5 [3  6  7]      7
> ```
>
> Constraints:
>
> ```
>  - 1 <= nums.length <= 10^5
> - 10^4 <= nums[i] <= 10^4
> - 1 <= k <= nums.length
> ```

Ques [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-window-maximum/)

My code: Test cases `37 / 51`

```js
const nums = [1,3,-1,-3,5,3,6,7], k = 3
let arr = [];
let j = k;
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  if (j <= nums.length) {
    let slicedArr = nums.slice(i, j);
    arr.push(Math.max(...slicedArr));
    j++
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

How can I optimize my code so that it can run all test cases?

Comment: When I run that code it takes between 0.1 and 0.7 ms. Seems pretty fast to me. I mean, you could move the `slice` into the `Math.max` line to remove the extra `slicedArr` variable. And I guess you could probably move all of it into a `reduce` method, but I'm not sure how much more efficient that would be.

Comment: I tried finding maximum from an array using `reduce` but I am getting the same issue of time on leetcode. Also, I tried what you suggested.

Comment: I benchmarked [reduce vs your original method](https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/19881/0/sliding-window-maximum-from-leetcode) and your method is anywhere between 24% to 150% faster, so I don't know what's up with Leetcode :).